# Calling ReportViewer.ServerReport.Render from IronPython

Tags: .net, asp.net, webforms, ironpython, reportviewer

I'm trying to call ReportViewer.ServerReport.Render similar to what we did in VB.NET or C# this way,

```
exportBytes = ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Render("PDF",None,mimeType,encoding,fileNameExtension,streamids,
Warning)
```

But I'm getting this error "expected Reference,but found null"

Answer (score 0):

ServerReport is null, probably the report viewer is not properly initialized.

Comment: You mean the properties of the ReportViewer? we have them in the same way in VB.NET and IronPython. I dont have any technical explanation but in VB.NET we pass "Nothing" as parameter and in IronPython we pass "None". Is that the same?

Comment: @Pablo, not exactly, I was guessing that ServerReport property of ReportViewer is null.